# Download with Curl makes the page load

Tags: javascript, php, curl, iframe

I'm trying to make a simple downloader:
I use a php script to download content from an URL that you can pass as a parameter. In order to download I use an hidden iframe in my main page:

```
<iframe id="downloader"></iframe>
```

I pass the URL that it has to be downloaded as a GET parameter with this js code:

```
function download(download) {
    $('#downloader').attr('src', 'Downloader.php?download='+download);
}
```

The Php script inside **Downloader.php** looks like this :

```
$download = $_GET['download'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $download);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//Check if $data is false --> Error

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$download.'"',true);
header('Expires: 0',true);
echo $data;
```

Now the actual "problem": When it downloads, the page changes its favicon to a spinning icon, I suppose it's because I'm changing the DOM. Is there a way I can download using iframe but without this loading icon or I'll have to download in another way?

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to achieve? This could be entirely done with javascript... And/or without iframe with a simple location.href

Answer (score 1):

The loading spinner occurs when the browser is retrieving data for the display of the page. This can mean it downloads a picture to display, or the page itself, its CSS or javascript files.

The same happens when using an IFrame, the frame's content being downloaded makes the browser show the loading spinner. The only way to avoid to show the spinner when downloading something, that I am aware of, is to use ajax.